# How to used for loop to create table in django form

Tags: python, html, django, pandas

I wish to have the following table :

```
Brand  Total  Price
  A      2      2
  T      4      9
  I      2      20
  B      9      9
Total    17     40
```

while Brand=['A','T','I','B'];Total=[2,4,2,9] and Price=[2,9,20,9]

views.py

```
context['LUnique'] = range(1,LUnique+1)
```

Header.html

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <table class="table table-bordered " border="1">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">JUSON Supermart</td>
        </tr>
        {% for i in LUnique %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{i.Brand|safe}}</td>
                <td>{{i.Total|safe}}</td>
                <td>{{i.Price|safe}}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
</div>
```

Anyone can help me on this because above code not return the table as i wish.

Comment: `LUnique` should be a QuerySet object.

Comment: Actually my LUnique is equal to 4

Comment: mean in here i want it loop 4 times, so any idea on this

Comment: Replace ` {% for i in LUnique %}<tr><td>{{i.Brand|safe}}</td><td>{{i.Total|safe}}</td><td>{{i.Price|safe}}</td></tr>{% endfor %}` with ` {% for i in LUnique %}<tr><td>{{i}}</td><td>{{i}}</td><td>{{i}}</td></tr>{% endfor %}` you should see the problem.

Comment: Any idea of make this looping? because the array all are dynamic actually, and i no idea how to make this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, aggregate all the three lists into tuples using [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) function.

**views.py**

```
Brand = ['A', 'T', 'I', 'B']
Total = [2, 4, 2, 9]
Price = [2, 9, 20, 9]

context = {'LUnique': zip(Brand, Total, Price)}
```

Then, iterate over it.

**header.html**

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <table class="table table-bordered " border="1">
        <tr><td colspan="4">JUSON Supermart</td></tr>
        {% for b, t, p in LUnique %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{b}}</td>
                <td>{{t}}</td>
                <td>{{p}}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}</table>
</div>
```

**Result:**

[image]